# How to edit Iframe src using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I need to dinamically change an iframe src on a loaded web page, using python selenium.

HTML of page:

```
<div id="regmail">
    <iframe src="URLTOCHANGE">
        code...
```

I access the iframe element in this way:

```
captcha_start = driver.find_element_by_id("regmail")
iframe = captcha_start.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

How can I change the iframe source url without store locally the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate the iframe by some tag or title.
ex:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("resultsFrame"))
```